# Mongo DB, Java Mongo API, how to add hint into aggregate command

Tags: java, mongodb

I stuck with Mongo with $hint command.
I have collection and i had indexed this collection. But the problem is, I query collection with Aggregate framework, but I want temporary disable Indexing, so I use hint command like this:

```
db.runCommand(
    {aggregate:"MyCollectionName", 
     pipeline:[{$match : {...somthing...},
               {$project : {...somthing...}}]
    }, 
    {$hint:{$natural:1}}
)
```

Please Note that I use `{$hint:{$natural:1}}` to disable Indexing for this query,
I have run SUCCESSFULLY this command on MongoDB command line. But I don't know how to map this command to Mongo Java Api (Java Code).

I used lib mongo-2.10.1.jar

Comment: No need for all the bold :/

Answer (score 6):

Currently you can't - it is on the backlog - please vote for [SERVER-7944](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7944)